# Comma with decimal value

Tags: c#

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = TextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
    long ul;
    if (long.TryParse(value, out ul))
        {
            TextBox.TextChanged -= TextBoxTextChanged;
            TextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:#,#0}", ul);
            TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
            TextBox.TextChanged += TextBoxTextChanged;
        }
}
```

I want to put comma with decimal value in calculator by pressing equal button in c# (Example : 1234.1234 to 1,234.1234)

But it is not giving my desire result. Could any kindly please help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextBox.Text = ul.ToString("#,##0.0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the name of your event and change the logic a little bit to handle the `.` without any number after it (eg `1.`) by appending a dot to your string. Like this:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = TextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
    decimal ul;
    if (decimal.TryParse(value, out ul))
    {
        TextBox.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
        if(ul % 1 == 0) // is the number integer
            TextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.#}", ul) + (TextBox.Text.EndsWith(".") ? "." : "");
        else
            TextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.0#####}", ul) ;
        TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
        TextBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
    }
}
```